# pop up doesn't close in .netframework 4.5.50709

Tags: c#, popup, .net-framework-version

I wrote a program that works properly with previous .netframeworks version. but after updating to 4.5.50709 it doesn't close when I click outside of the pop up region. It should be noticed that the problem doesn't exist in 4.5.50710 but since some customers may have 4.5.50709 installed on their PCs, I have to solve the issue in 4.5.50709.

Comment: Please post reproduction code here. Maybe you could try to require a specific version via a manifest file (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Samuel: what is reproduction code?

Comment: @fasadat see [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)